# ios - Drawing Brush from finger toches moves

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-core

i want to draw in my iPad app as in the following image

[image]
in my app i have placed a image and while moving the finger(touch movement) i am repeating the images, but my image seems to be as follows.

[image]

Following is my code to draw the image

```
            CGBlendMode blendMode = kCGBlendModeColorDodge;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
            [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

////            NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Watercolor-edge-45x45.png" ofType:nil];
            UIImage * textureColor;// = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            float angle = hypot(deltaX, deltaY);
            angle *= rand() % 180;//(M_PI / 180);
            CGPoint vector = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x - lastPoint.x, currentPoint.y - lastPoint.y);
            CGFloat distance = hypotf(vector.x, vector.y);
            vector.x /= distance;
            vector.y /= distance;
            for (CGFloat i = 0; i < distance; i += 1.0f) {
                textureColor = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[self CGImageRotatedByAngle:image angle:angle * -1]];
                CGPoint p = CGPointMake(lastPoint.x + i * vector.x, lastPoint.y + i * vector.y);
                [textureColor drawAtPoint:p blendMode:blendMode alpha:0.1f];
            }
            CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            UIImage *newimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

How to get the my image as in the first image

Actually i have an image and fill the selected color to the image and started drawing here i have a image
[image]

Comment: Change brush color to red?  It's hard to tell, they might have their own artistic blend mode and randomly varying brush.  For one thing, they start with a more saturated color (higher alpha), yours looks more like airbrush.

Comment: how your setting the color instead of setting the color as green you set [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern2.jpg"]] color like this and your image be smaller piece...

Comment: hi, thanks for your feedback,In the above i have edited for your question

Comment: your using this CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); instead of this u try these two values 
  kCGLineCapButt,kCGLineCapSquare

Comment: ya, i changed these types still i didnt get the shapes could you help me please

Comment: I am also want to paint on imageview by water color. Did you got any solution for that ? If yes then please share it.

Comment: No, still now i didnt get any solution.if I have any means i will share to you

Comment: Hi dinesh, did you find the any solution ? please reply me. thanks

Comment: Can you provide us with more of your sample project?